# Nested maps in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I want to transform my list `list = [" a , 1 ", " b , 2 "]` into a nested list `[["a","1"],["b","2"]]`.

The following works:

```
f1_a = map(lambda x :[t.strip() for t in x.split(',',1)],list)
```

but this does not work with Python 3 (it does work with Python 2.7!):

```
f1_b = map(lambda x :map(lambda t:t.strip(),x.split(',',1)),list)
```

Why is that?

Is there a more concise way then `f1_4` to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python 3's [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns a `map` object, which you need to convert to list explicitly:

```
f1_b = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda t: t.strip(), x.split(',', 1))), lst))
```

Though in most cases you should prefer list comprehensions to `map` calls:

```
f1_a = [[t.strip() for t in x.split(',', 1)] for x in lst]
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting "x.replace" over "x.strip"?

Comment: @JohnPrawyn: to get rid of one loop: `[t.strip() for t in x.split(',', 1)]` would become `x.replace(' ', '').split(',')`. On the other hand, now I see that the suggestion is restricted to the data in the question and will fail on more complex examples. I removed it from my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Python3 map function returns map object and that object need to typecast in list.

```py
num = [" a , 1 ", " b , 2 "]

list1 = list(map(lambda x:x.split(','), num))

print(list1)
```

Output:

```
[[' a ', ' 1 '], [' b ', ' 2 ']]
```